# Is it required to use 'mut' constraint with Signer in subsequent contexts?

Tags: anchor

After reading docs, I understand that we have to mark Signer account as mut in the initialize context like this:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SetupGame<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = player_one, space = 8 + Game::MAXIMUM_SIZE)]
    pub game: Account<'info, Game>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub player_one: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}
```

But what if we subsequently use this signer's account in the other context inside `has_one` command? Do we have to add 'mut' constraint in that context? If no then why do we mark Signer's account mutable in the initialize context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to mark accounts that have changes as mut. Changes include balance changes as a result of paying the rent for an account or token balance changes.

So unless the signer is the fee payer or is getting changed somehow, you don’t need mut on the signer.

Comment: From fee, you mean account creation fee, right? Normal transaction fee doesn't account for fee, correct? Or does it have the meaning in the sense of `writable` account?

Comment: Yes, you need to mark any account that is changing in any way as mut. Regarding transaction fees, you can split it out to an explicit payer. 
For example: 
#[account(mut)]
pub payer: Signer<'info>